# Use exclusive mode of H2 database - Java

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I am using H2 database to execute in memory sql query. The mode I exclusively want to use is  MSSQLServer syntax.

```
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.h2.Driver());
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test-database;MODE=MSSQLServer");
```

But when I execute this SQL query which is a MySQL syntax it works :

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10
```

1-How is it possible ?

2-How to force a single mode when executing query ?

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: H2 already supports both the `TOP` and `LIMIT` syntaxes. You can see these in the [select documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html?highlight=select&search=select#select). The list of features for SQL Server [compatibility mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) is limited, and the documentation there says "_only a small subset of the differences between databases are implemented_".

Comment: yes H2 supports both TOP and LIMIT syntaxes. But in the case of choosing explicitly the MSSQLServer Mode the "LIMIT" syntax is no longer supposed to work. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I think these compatibility features are provided "as well as" H2 features, where they can co-exist, such as `+` and `concat()`, or "instead of" where they cannot co-exist, such as "Arguments of LOG() function are swapped." The list of such features is small, as you can see - and `TOP` is not even mentioned. To take it to the extreme: I don't think compatibility mode means "all of the features of MS SQL Server's SQL implementation - and _only_ those features". But all of this is only based on my interpretation of the documentation, and my observations of H2's behavior. I could be wrong.